# Transitivity Reduction in Javascript

Tags: javascript, algorithm, graph-algorithm

I am working on determining transitivity for the given routes, based on the following input

```
[
    {
        id: 1,
        vessel: 'Vessel 1',
        routeId: 1,
        port: 'HK',
        eta: null,
        etd: '2016-01-03 00:00:00'
    },
    {
        id: 2,
        vessel: 'Vessel 1',
        routeId: 1,
        port: 'SG',
        eta: '2016-01-06 00:00:00',
        etd: '2016-01-09 00:00:00'
    },
    {
        id: 3,
        vessel: 'Vessel 3',
        routeId: 2,
        port: 'SG',
        eta: '2016-01-12 00:00:00',
        etd: '2016-01-14 00:00:00'
    },
    {
        id: 4,
        vessel: 'Vessel 3',
        routeId: 2,
        port: 'OAK',
        eta: '2016-01-18 00:00:00',
        etd: null
    },
    {
        id: 5,
        vessel: 'Vessel 4',
        routeId: 3,
        port: 'OAK',
        eta: '2016-01-21 00:00:00',
        etd: '2016-01-23 00:00:00'
    },
    {
        id: 6,
        vessel: 'Vessel 4',
        routeId: 3,
        port: 'LAX',
        eta: '2016-01-28 00:00:00',
        etd: null
    }
];
```

If you look at the individual routes based on the **routeID** key,

routeID: 1, we have

> HK --> SG

routeID:2, we have

> SG --> OAK

routeID:3, we have

> OAK --> LA

Now transitivity applies across two different routeIDs and based on the above paths, we can say there is valid transitivity for

> HK --> OAK,   HK --> LA,   SG --> LA

My original approach on working for this problem, was to first create a object/set of destination to source for individual route which would look like this

```
  {
    1:{
      HK: [SG],
      SG: []

    },
    2:{
      SG: [US],
      US: []
    },
    3:{
      US: [USLA],
      USLA: []

    }
  }
```

Then I would use the above original input to go through each item and using the set created determine the if there is transitivity across different routeID. But I would like assistance with this problem, as my current thought process seem to not get the desired result.

**EDIT**

The expected output would be

```
[
      { 
        vessels: ['Vessel 1', 'Vessle 3'],
        routeIds: [1, 2],
        origin: 'HK',
        destination: 'OAK',
        etd: '2016-01-03 00:00:00',
        eta: '2016-01-18 00:00:00'
      },
      {
        vessels: ['Vessel 1', 'Vessel 3', 'Vessel 4'],
        routeIds: [1, 2, 3],
        origin: 'HK',
        destination: 'LA',
        etd: '2016-01-03 00:00:00',
        eta: '2016-01-28 00:00:00'
      },
      { 
        vessels: ['Vessel 3', 'Vessel 4'],
        routeIds: [2, 3],
        origin: 'SG',
        destination: 'LA',
        etd: '2016-01-14 00:00:00',
        eta: '2016-01-28 00:00:00'
      }
]
```

Comment: This seems like one of those problems that could be made much easier by changing the way the data is represented. You basically have a small graph, but you're not really representing the way graphs a typically represented. In your original array, what does each object represent?

Comment: @MarkMeyer the original data is being received from a server so don't have much control on that. Each object can be represented as a port or a stop

Comment: What you are asking for help with is unclear. Please clarify the desired output or how you would know if we answered your question.

Comment: @גלעדברקן i have edited the question with the expected output

Comment: your data structure is quite unclear, if you take the original array with two items for the same `routeId`. it would be easier, if you add a falf or any other hint if the item is a start/departure item or an target/arrival item. then you could generate the specific wanted result set.

Comment: Presumably you also have a minimum transshipment time?

Answer (score 0):

You could take an object for the given routes and use a function to check id a single route is avalable.

```js
const
    check = (from, to) => routes[from] 
        ? routes[from].some(t => t === to || check(t, to))
        : false;

var routes = { HK: ['SG'], SG: ['OAK'], OAK:['LA'] };

console.log([
    ['HK', 'OAK'], // true
    ['HK', 'LA'],  // true
    ['SG', 'LA'],  // true
    ['LA', 'OAK']  // false
].map(a => check(...a)));
```